# Question Regarding XML Parsing Using SAX in JAVA

Tags: java, xml, sax, xml-parsing, docx

I am trying to parse an XML document in Java (first time attempting to do so), and I have found a number of articles on Google that provide examples but I really don't understand some of the code in them, so I was wondering if someone could explain a few things to me. The primary example I was looking at came from here: [http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/org.xml.sax/parsing-xml-with-a-simple-sax-document-handler-2.html](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/org.xml.sax/parsing-xml-with-a-simple-sax-document-handler-2.html/%22SAX%20Example%22).

My main questions primarily come from the second half of the code, specifically the part of...

```
 // we enter to element 'qName':
        public void startElement(String uri, String localName, 
                String qName, Attributes attrs) throws SAXException {

            if (qName.equals("purchase-order")) {
            } else if (qName.equals("date")) {
            } /* if (...)
                        } */ else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Element '" + 
                        qName + "' is not allowed here");
                        }
        }

        // we leave element 'qName' without any actions:
        public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {
            // do nothing;
        }
```

...could someone explain to me what exactly "String uri, String localName, String qName, and Attributes attrs are? I assume they are not code specific as I've seen them in a few examples. Also (assuming) that these are some sort of root elements in the XML file, could anyone provide some direction as to how I could use these to parse through the "document.xml.rels" file located within a .docx directory in a way that it would read and accept only the image files (not header, settings, etc) and their associated Relationship Id #'s? (Below is the short document I'm referring to)...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
- <Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
      <Relationship Id="rId8" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/footer" Target="footer1.xml" /> 
      <Relationship Id="rId13" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/theme" Target="theme/theme1.xml" /> 
      <Relationship Id="rId3" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/settings" Target="settings.xml" /> 
      <Relationship Id="rId7" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/header" Target="header1.xml" /> 
      <Relationship Id="rId12" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/fontTable" Target="fontTable.xml" /> 
      <Relationship Id="rId2" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/styles" Target="styles.xml" /> 
      <Relationship Id="rId1" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/numbering" Target="numbering.xml" /> 
      <Relationship Id="rId6" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/endnotes" Target="endnotes.xml" /> 
      <Relationship Id="rId11" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/image" Target="media/image3.png" /> 
      <Relationship Id="rId5" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/footnotes" Target="footnotes.xml" /> 
      <Relationship Id="rId10" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/image" Target="media/image2.jpeg" /> 
      <Relationship Id="rId4" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/webSettings" Target="webSettings.xml" /> 
      <Relationship Id="rId9" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/image" Target="media/image1.jpeg" /> 
</Relationships>
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: "I have found a number of articles on Google that provide examples but I really don't understand some of the code in them." Is that really the best way to proceed? Learning from examples is essentially trial and error. You need to find a spec of the facilities you are using, read it, and understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the javadoc of SAX [`ContentHandler.startElement(..)`](http://www.saxproject.org/apidoc/org/xml/sax/ContentHandler.html#startElement%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.xml.sax.Attributes%29)

Comment: @Peter Knego So from that link, I assume all those things are required? In regards to the xml document I posted, what would be the respective uri, localName, qName, and attrs?

Comment: Your document does not declare namespace, so `uri` will be empty string.

Comment: `localName` and `qName` should both contain `Relationship`. This is a bit implementation specific (depends on concrete SAX parser). Check to see what you get.

Comment: Ahh, my mistake. Your root element contains namespace declaration `xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships"`.

Comment: I think this best describes what happens with namespaces: http://www.saxproject.org/namespaces.html

Comment: @Peter Knego, so I have the same question I asked Nathan. If I wanted to parse through each of the necessary attributes, do I need any commands within the if statements? Like in the example above, his if statements are all just blank. Do you not need to do anything within those statements?

Comment: Also, judging from your questions above, I believe there is some confusion about how SAX works: it is an event-based API. It'll go through your XML and call methods in your Handler for every type of SAX/XML events. Those events are start/end document, start/end element and character event. So, in your case, `startElement()` will be called for `Relationships` and for every `Relationship`, total 14 times (1+13). MOre about this: http://www.saxproject.org/event.html

Comment: So according to that, the breakdown would be something like...

uri = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships"
qName & localName = Relationships
attrs = Relationship Id, Target

?

Comment: So from what I got from that, for each occurrence (or event) of a document/element, a method is going to be called from the handler. So when you go through the conditional if statements (like in the example above), whenever the parser finds an instance of that event, it will know what method to call, thus why there is no need to specify anything within the if statements themselves? Or am I way off base with my interpretation?

Comment: NO, `uri=http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships`, localName= Relationships or Relationship, attributes are Id, Type, Target (but only if localName=Relationship)

Comment: can u explain how localName could be either Relationship OR Relationships?

Comment: Xml elements are defined by brackets, start element `<something>`, end element `</something>`, characters are text inside elements `<a>some text</a>`, attributes are attr=value pair inside element declarations `<a attribute1=xxx, attribute2=yyy>`. Empty XML elements have no characters `<a/>`

Comment: So, you need `if(localName.equals("Relationship")){attrs.getValue("Id")}`

Comment: localName = Relationships or Relationship? They are both names of XML elements: `<Relationships>` and `<Relationship>`. SAX parser just calls your code when it detects a start of XML element, i.e. it encounters `<Relationships>`, `<Relationship>` or `<something>`. It does not care. You must check if name of element id what you need.

Comment: This is why SAX is called event-based parser. It produces events based on what it encounters in XML stream. Pls read this  http://www.saxproject.org/event.html

Comment: Hmm, and since I assume this is parsing top to bottom, left to right...there probably is no way to identify the Target attribute prior to the Id is there?

Comment: Yes it is: SAX reads whole `<Relationship Id=xx Target=yy>` element and calls your code `startElement()`. All attributes are inside `Attributes` object.

Comment: Haha, wow, that link you just provided put everything into crystal clear light lol. Definitely understand 'events' now at least. Just want to say thank you very much for your help up to this point, really learning a lot here, appreciate it.

Comment: Personally I find SAX pretty gruesome. I prefer JAXB - it maps XML to your classes: http://ondra.zizka.cz/stranky/programovani/java/jaxb/jaxb-howto-introduction-tutorial.texy

Comment: Only advantage of SAX is that it's VERY fast and it uses virtually no memory.

Comment: Not exactly what I want the end output to be, but in general, is this what I would basically write to pull out the target value and id value for only the image files?

`if(localName.equals("Relationship"))
       {
        if(attrs.equals("Target"))
        {
         if(attrs.getValue("Target").contains("image"))
         {
          String id = attrs.getValue("Id");
          String target = attrs.getValue("Target");
          System.out.println("Id: " + id + "& Target: " + target);
         }
        }
          }`

Comment: And for what I'm doing now, working with a large number of docx files, I think I should at least give SAX a try. However, I definitely will look into JAXB if SAX gets too cumbersome.

Comment: If you do decide to try JAXB, then docx4j will make that easy for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
URI :   Namespace URI
LOCAL NAME : the local name (without prefix)
QName : the qualified XML name (with prefix)
```